# My links overlap when the screen is resized

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I used a inline navbar for my website, but when I scale the window there are problems, for instance if I shrink my window the links padding will show up on the opposite side of the page. If I shrink it all the way the window all the way if you hover over a link it will cover the one on top.

```css
li{
 display:inline;
}
ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:20px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color:#383a3d;
}
a.list:link{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:100% 10%;
}
a.list:hover{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1.header{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
}
body{
 background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
header, footer{
 background-color:#ffab3d;
 padding:30px;
 margin:0;
}
nav{
 position:fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Varistyle.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header><h1 class="header">Varisent</h1></header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="list" href="#home">Home<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#about">About Us<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#service">Services<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#contact">Contact Us<a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent `ul` and `flex-grow: 1` on the `li`'s (or `flex: 1 0 0` for short) and they'll scale to fit the width of the header, and shrink without overlapping.

```css
li{
 flex: 1 0 0;
}
ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:20px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color:#383a3d;
  display: flex;
}
a.list:link{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:100% 10%;
}
a.list:hover{
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1.header{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
}
body{
 background-color:#f7f7f7;
}
header, footer{
 background-color:#ffab3d;
 padding:30px;
 margin:0;
}
nav{
 position:fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Varistyle.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header><h1 class="header">Varisent</h1></header>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="list" href="#home">Home<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#about">About Us<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#service">Services<a></li>
    <li><a class="list" href="#contact">Contact Us<a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```